Meaning of "go one's way"
What does "go way" mean in this sentence?

GOAL - Fulham 3-1 Newcastle
Reiss Nelson Awful mistake by Bruno Guimaraes who passes straight to
Reiss Nelson and the substitute makes no mistake.
The points are going Fulham's way.


Please note that it's "go <someone's> way".  "Go way" by itself wouldn't make any sense.

If the points (or things, the game, the situation, etc.) are "going someone's way", it means as the ongoing activity progresses / changes, it's doing so in a way which is favourable to that "someone". In your example, Fulham are scoring goals / gaining points.

'Everything's Going my Way' was a well known song when I was a boy.

Normally when something is "going someone's way" it means that things are favourable to that person. "The game is going Fulham's way" means that the circumstances of the game are favourable to Fulham.
However in this particular case I think it means that the points (for winning the game) are going to be awarded to Fulham. The commentators is stating that this seals the game in favour of Fulham, who will therefore receive the points for winning.

Yes, I think the sense is that the points are going in the direction of Fulham (way 8a), in other words headed towards being awarded to Fulham not their opponent. Although "way" suggests it's not absolutely final, just tending towards a Fulham win. Specifically it refers to the 3 points for a win in the league competition, rather than the number of goals scored on the pitch.

Here is the meaning
Ref. Merriam Webster dictionary:

go someone's way.
2. : to happen in a way that helps someone.

It means that the mistake by  Bruno Guimaraes (of Newcastle) helped Reiss Nelson (of Fulham) score a goal.

It could mean that, but I think in this context it means "the points are going to be awarded to Fulham."

DJClayworth I  In this match all three goals were scored by the substitute player Reiss Nelson. https://www.skysports.com/football/news/11661/13217326/fulham-3-1-newcastle-united-magpies-miss-out-on-chance-to-go-top-of-the-premier-league-after-first-loss
